# I accidentally formatted my drive. Can I use a backup .img file to recover it?

Tags: 22.04, data-recovery, dd

I have accidentally formatted my drive. Attempts at data recovery have been unsuccessful, but I had created an `.img` file of the drive with `dd if=/dev/sd<x> of=filename.img` before that.

So I wanna know, is the `.img` file an exact copy of the drive? I mean, is it ok to do my data recovery using the `.img` file by writing the `.img` file to the formatted drive?

Comment: You can also extract the img file and copy-paste the data

Answer (score 7):

**A general answer is yes - if the backup is good**. But you should always *test* that a backup & restore method works *before you need it*.

A backup from drive **a** to drive **b** can be tested by restoring it to drive **c**.

---

**Cloning and/or making an image of the whole drive** should be done with superuser privileges (best with `sudo` but possible also when running as root). So I guess that you used the following method

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sd<x> of=filename.img
```

where `<x>` is the drive letter, for example `a` or `b` or `c`.

**Please notice that you should also restore it to the whole drive** (the original drive or another drive with at least the same size).

It is extremely important that you **write to the correct drive**. If you write to the wrong drive, important data might be lost forever. So **please check and doublecheck** before you use

```
sudo dd if=filename.img of=/dev/sd<x>
```

The process will be faster, if you increase the number of bytes written each time

```
sudo dd if=filename.img of=/dev/sd<x> bs=4096
```

An alternative is to **use a tool with a 'final checkpoint'** in order to wrap a safety belt around the restore process. [mkusb and mkusb-nox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) can do it with a final checkpoint in Ubuntu. [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) can do it with a final checkpoint in Windows.